# spinner list not showing my action bar?

Tags: android

```
private void setListNavigation(ActionBar bar) {
    String[] actions = new String[] {
        "Bookmark",
            "Subscribe",
            "Share"
    };
    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // hide application title from action bar
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#dedfde")));

}
```

When i try to add spinner to my action bar, it does not show up. I just get the small arrow icon alone.

Below is my `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prime_mobile_home);               
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    setListNavigation(bar);       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working code to setting navigational spinner in action bar try this out

```
arrayItemsForDropdown = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.order);
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,R.array.order, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add

> bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);

in your `setListNavigation`

and let your class implement ActionBar.OnNavigationListener